# What type of Shower Valve Stem is this? I need to replace the handle

Tags: plumbing

Ive tried every outlet i can to identify the type of stem i have in order to replace my shower handle. My plumbing supply told me its an American Standard but every American Standard handle i see does not have the same broach. May i have some help identifying the type of Shower Stem/Shower Valve kit i would need? or even the brand/models that are compatible. Thanks!

[image: Shower Valve]

[image: Shower Valve Broach]

[image: Shower Handle Insert]

Comment: That's a tough one.  Maybe you can find a cartridge identification guide like this one that has more broaches:  https://content.interlinebrands.com/product/document/10145/133938_Brochure.pdf